# Do Cordova apps run any code or start loading anything while the splash screen is still visible?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have an app that does some bootstrapping when the app is first launched to go out and fetch some data from a server. It seems to be taking a very long time on the splash screen and I'm just wondering if any of this pre-processing is done while the splash screen is open, and if so, are there any good ways to optimize this on the app's initial load?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The SplashScreen shows while the native side of Cordova loads. Once all the device API's are done loadings it should go away. Unless you're specifically setting a time delay on the SplashScreen or you have a lot of plugins installed, it shouldn't be taking too long. Look at your device logs to see exactly whats going on.